# add pvalues to boxplot from two-way anova using ggpubr

Tags: r, ggpubr

I have a data set with multiple factors, at the moment I am comparing two of them with a box plot.

I have downloaded `ggpubr`, and am using, `stat_compare_means()` to add p-values.

However, I would like to have p-values for all 4 comparisons. This only gives me 2.

I have looked through the on-line examples and I can see how to make your own comparisons using `my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )`
but this is for different levels of the same factor.

So, for example with the tooth growth example I want p-values comparing `OJ/D1` to `OJ/D0.5`.

Here is my code:

```
OTU<-colnames(df)[j]
ggplot(subset(df,variable==OTU),
   aes(x=Fungi,y=abund,fill=Insect))+geom_boxplot()+
stat_compare_means()+
 ggtitle(paste(OTU,location,sep="_”))
```

Here is my data:

```
> df[1:5,1:5]
      Location Bean Fungi Insect Acaulospora
R-B1       Root Bean    NF     NI           0
R-B2       Root Bean    NF     NI           0
R-B3       Root Bean    NF     NI           0
R-BF-1     Root Bean Fungi     NI           0
R-BF-2     Root Bean Fungi     NI           0
```

I want p-values for `Fungi_Insect` vs `NF_Insect` as well as `Fungi_Insect` vs. `Fungi_NI` etc.

Any help appreciated.